# Page Refresh problem

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp in which there are certain buttons when i am clicking 
on one of those, the page is refreshing but the problem is that I
want to show that section of jsp where the button is on  which 
the user has done the on click event...but the section which is 
coming is the top of the page but I don't want that.
Please provide me with a solution to rectify the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The details depend on what happens when the user clicks the button, but either way, the solution is to use Javascript.

If the user's click changes something about the user interface (for example, expand a folder, or add something to a list), use Javascript to make the change on the fly.  If the click is meant to submit something to the back-end, use AJAX to make it happen (as Pandiya suggested).

And AJAX is quite simple to learn.  Really, you just need to get familiar with a few new function calls and you're most of the way there.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hai Abhi,

If i understood your question try using ajax to submit a particular form in jsp...